# How do you make a block give a particle effect when you stand on it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you make a block give a particle effect when you stand on it? I need it chained to a command block that sets your spawn point when you stand on said block.

Comment: Can you show/tell us what you've already tried? Arqade tends to work better when you show us what you already tried an researched yourself!

Comment: Have you tried `execute detect` and `/particle`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your question did not specify, this will be a two part answer. The first one will be if you mean if the player is standing on a specific block *type*, and the second will be for if the player is standing on a block in a specific *location*.

---

First:

The following command will run `</command>` on the player with `<block>` under them. The `-1` means the block below them, however I'd actually recommend -2 or -3 so the detected block can be arbitrary, and below the floor, then it doesn't have to be seen.

```
/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ <block> </command>
```

to set the spawn point of the player that's on top of the block use:

```
/spawnpoint @s
```

In place of `</command>`

`@s` selects the entity that *executed* the command, it can be useful.

Then for the particles have another `/execute` with a `/particle` command

---

Second:

If you want only specific locations, not specified by the block the player is standing on, use something like this:

```
/spawnpoint @a[x=<x>,y=<y>,z=<z>,r=<r>]
```

`<x>,<y>` and `<z>` would be the coordinates of the location of the *feet* of the player he has to be to set the spawn point. `r=<r>` is unnecessary, but setting an `<r>` value lets you have an area instead of an exact point for spawn points.

Then for the particles use a similar selector in a `/execute ... /particle` command, just no `detect` part.

---

The above methods, if used in a repeating command block will set the players spawn point *every tick*, and it will do the same with the particles, which could cause frame issues if you're spawning a lot of particles.

I don't have a good idea on how to solve this problem right now. If you could give some information on what you need this for I might be able to think of a solution.

Hopefully you get whatever you're working on, working.